# Solving a system of coupled bvp ode equations using scipy's solve_bvp for stellar modeling

Tags: python, scipy, modeling, ode, astronomy

I'm trying to solve the basic equations for stellar modeling using python. I have the system of ODEs and the variables needed:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Constants (for now)

G = 6.67e-8
X = 0.71
Y = 0.28
Z = 0.01
#Mr is the mass contained within a certain radius
#kappa is opacity
#nabla is the energy transport assuming the whole star is radiative
#rho is density
#r, P, L, T is max radius, pressure, luminosity, and temperature respectively 
def coupled_differential_equations(P, T, r, L, Mr):

  #rho = (P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T))

  #kappa = (4e25*(1+X)*(Z+1e-3)*(P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T)/(T**3.5)))

  #nabla = ((3 * 4e25*(1+X)*(Z+1e-3)*(P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T)/(T**3.5)) * L * P)/(16 * np.pi * 1.38e-23 * T**4)*(1 / G * Mr))

  dr_dMr = (1 / (4 * np.pi * r**2 * P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T)))
  dP_dMr = -((G * Mr) / (4 * np.pi * r**4))
  dL_dMr = 9.5 * 10e-37 * X**2 * (P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T))**2 * T**4
  dT_dMr = -(((3 * 4e25*(1+X)*(Z+1e-3)*(P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T)/(T**3.5)) * L * P)/(16 * np.pi * 1.38e-23 * T**4)*(1 / G * Mr))*(T/P))*((G * M)/(4 * np.pi * r**4))
  return np.vstack([dr_dMr, dP_dMr, dL_dMr, dT_dMr])

 #***************************************************************************

def boundary_conditions(ya, yb, P, T, L, Mr):
  # Boundary conditions at the center
  center_conditions = np.array([ya[0], ya[2], ya[3]])
    # Boundary conditions at the surface
  surface_conditions = np.array([yb[1], yb[3] - 1e-6, yb[2] - Mr])
  return np.concatenate([center_conditions, surface_conditions])
#Current issue is that P, T, r, L, Mr, kappa is not defined outside of the function??? seems to require initial guess but it's a bvp so it shouldn't need one???

# Initial values and range for r
initial_r = 1e-3
final_r = 3.9e5

x = np.linspace(initial_r, final_r, 100)
y_a = np.zeros((4, x.size))
# Solve BVP using solve_bvp 
sol = solve_bvp(coupled_differential_equations, boundary_conditions, x, y_a)


# Extract the solution
r_solution = sol.x
y_solution = sol.y

# Plot the results
plt.plot(r_solution, y_solution[0], label='r')
plt.plot(r_solution, y_solution[1], label='P')
plt.plot(r_solution, y_solution[2], label='L')
plt.plot(r_solution, y_solution[3], label='T')
plt.xlabel('r')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The boundary conditions are the center of the star and the surface. At the center (Mr=0), r=0, and l=0. At the surface (Mr=M, all the mass), rho=0, T = (L/(8pi(r^2)sigma)^(1/4), where sigma is the Boltzman constant.

When I run the code, it is currently saying that the coupled_differential_equations parameter in the `sol = solve_bvp(coupled_differential_equations, boundary_conditions, x, y_a)` is missing arguments, but when I added in (Mr, P, T, L, r, kappa), it says that the varibles are not defined. The scipy handbook (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_bvp.html) seemed to not need arguments when plugging the system of odes into the solve_bvp.

Do I need to have an initial guess (something like the shooting method)? I'm a bit lost on what to do right now...

I'm still rather new to coding, but if anyone can give some pointers on how to get the solve_bvp to work, or honestly anything else I'm doing wrong, I'd appreciate it a lot!

Comment: So, there are a couple of issues. Before I can help, in the `dT_dMr` equation you use `nabla` like a function when it isn't. Should there be a multiplication symbol there? You also have an `M` there. Should that be `Mr`? And you have `kappa` as an argument but you define `kappa` in the function. Which is it, an argument or something you compute in the function?

Comment: Also, what is your dependent variable, is it `Mr`?

Comment: As I go through this more, there are a lot more issues than I initially thought. Please clarify what your dependent and independent variables are. And if you have 4 first-order ODEs then you can only have 4 boundary conditions. What are those boundary conditions?

Comment: Mr is the independent variable. And I'm not sure how else to put nabla into the dt_dMr equation? And yes the M should be an Mr. They are all related so I was told that everything in the coupled_differiential_function should be solved simultaneously. I think kappa should be a function? In that case I'm guessing I shouldn't include it in the argument. Thank you so much!

Comment: The dependent variables are r, P, T, and L. However things like rho (density), nabla (energy transport), and kappa (opacity) are needed in the differentials. The boundary conditions at the center of the star (Mr = 0) are r=0 and L=0. At the surface, (Mr = M), they are rho = 0 and T = (L/(8pi(r^2)sigma)^(1/4), where sigma is the Boltzman constant.

Comment: You are going to have some interesting boundary conditions at r=0 with those equations.

Comment: @cat_1028 So what are `nabla` and `kappa`? You define them as scalars in your function. And if `Mr` is your independent variable, then why are you using `r` to set the domain, it should be `Mr`, though you say that `Mr = M` at the surface yet you haven't said what `M` is.

Comment: @cat_1028 I don't know anything about the Stellar structure, but I do know differential equations and how to solve them numerically. That said, the Wikipedia page on the [Stellar structure](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stellar_structure) has the ODEs as differentials with respect to `r`. Where are your ODEs from that they are with respect to `Mr`, which I assume is mass as a function of `r`?

Comment: @jared Mr is the mass within a radius. Small r is the actual radius of a star, or like the max radius. Same thing for M, it's the maximum mass of a star, and yes I will set a constant (i.e. mass of the sun) for that. These equations are based of Mr instead of r (as a variable radius from the center of star) because stars can be unstable, and radius will vary as a function of time. Using a mass-shell eliminates that complication as we can assume the maximum mass of a star will be constant.

Comment: Kappa is the opacity, which is complex and varies at different densities and temperatures, so for simplification we decided to use one for higher temps, and is a function of rho and T. Nabla is the equation for radiative energy transport and is a function of kappa, T, and Mr.

Comment: Please write your equations without nabla. You are writing it both as a variable and a function, which is wrong anyway. Your major problem is the expression for dT/dMr. Are you sure that the surface boundary condition has T=0? Such a star would emit no radiation. Finally, please eradicate those magic numbers - they come from physical constants, but the units are so unusual outside of the astrophysical field that it is very difficult to see if they are correct.

Comment: @lastchance Apologies, I've edited the original question and the outer boundary condition for T should be fixed. I'm not sure how to exclude nabla; do you mean to substitute the nabla in the dT/dMr equation? In that case, should I also substitute kappa into nabla, and same thing with rho so that even if the equations get long it would only be in terms of P, T, L, r, and Mr? Also to clarify about the magic numbers, the X, Y, and Z are chemical abundances, while G is a converted gravitational constant. I'm not too worried about them right now though.

Comment: Yes, I meant to substitute your expression for nabla directly into dT_dMr. However, with Mr as the independent variable, all of your gradients are going to become infinite at r=0, which is going to produce severe numerical problems. I don't know what you are trying to do with the boundary conditions: at the centre r=0 and L=0 (so ya[0] and ya[2]), whilst at the surface P=0 and T=0 (or fixed) (so yb[1] and yb[3]). There is no need for any additional parameters in either coupled_differential_equations() or boundary_conditions().

Comment: @lastchance Thank you for the clarification! I've substituted the rho, kappa, and nabla in the original question. The parameters should now just be (P, L, T, r, Mr)? Is it possible to solve it with a boundary value very close to r=0, like r = 0.0001? I'm rather confused about how to input the boundary conditions since T is not a constant...

Answer (score 1):

There is still a lot missing, so this answer will be incomplete, but I will address some of your issues (mostly syntax) and tell you what you're missing.

First of all, for `scipy.integrate.solve_bvp` the ODE function signature should be `f(x, y)`. You currently do not have that because you're passing all the `y` values independently and have `x` at the end. Here is what it should look like:

```py
def coupled_differential_equations(x, y):
    Mr = x
    P, T, r, L = y    
    dr_dMr = (1 / (4 * np.pi * r**2 * P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T)))
    dP_dMr = -((G * Mr) / (4 * np.pi * r**4))
    dL_dMr = 9.5 * 10e-37 * X**2 * (P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T))**2 * T**4
    dT_dMr = -(((3 * 4e25*(1+X)*(Z+1e-3)*(P*(2.1945*1e-3)/(0.0821*T)/(T**3.5)) * L * P)/(16 * np.pi * 1.38e-23 * T**4)*(1 / G * Mr))*(T/P))*((G * Mr)/(4 * np.pi * r**4))
    return np.vstack([dr_dMr, dP_dMr, dL_dMr, dT_dMr])
```

(I also replaced the `M` with `Mr` since `M` is undefined, but maybe `M` should be defined somewhere.

Second of all, the boundary condition function should have the function signature `bc(ya, yb)`, but again you're passing more. Here, `ya` and `yb` will contain the values of `P`, `T`, `r`, and `L` (in that order) at the initial and final mesh locations, respectively. You have a system of 4 first-order ODEs, so you can only specify 4 boundary conditions. That's a mathematical requirement (otherwise you overdefine the system). Here is what your boundary condition should look like:

```py
def boundary_conditions(ya, yb):
    # At the center (Mr=0), r=0, and l=0
    # At the surface (Mr=M, all the mass), rho=0, T = (L/(8pi(r^2)sigma)^(1/4),
    # where sigma is the Boltzman constant.
    center_conditions = [ya[2], ya[3]]
    surface_conditions = [yb[1] - (L/(8*np.pi*yb[2]**2*sigma))**0.25, ??]
    return np.array(center_conditions + surface_conditions)
```

The issue here is (1) you're missing one of the boundary conditions (I'm not sure how you get `rho` from the other values) and (2) you need to define sigma somewhere (that's simple).

Once you have these, you need to fix how you're calling the function. Since `Mr` is your independent variable and not `r` (I'm not sure why you've done it this way, but you have), your mesh `x` must be the range of values for `Mr` instead. I don't know what those are, so you will have to fill them in.

```py
Mr_initial = ??
Mr_final = ??
Mr = np.linspace(Mr_initial, Mr_final, 100)
```

The remaining lines will be:

```py
y0 = np.zeros((4, Mr.size))
sol = solve_bvp(coupled_differential_equations, boundary_conditions, Mr, y0)

y_solutions = sol.y

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 4)
labels = ["P", "T", "r", "L"]
for y_sol, label, ax in zip(y_solutions, plot_labels, axes):
    ax.plot(Mr, y_sol)
    ax.set_xlabel("Mr")
    ax.set_ylabel(label)
fig.show()
```

Note: I changed the order of the plot labels to match the ordering in `coupled_differential_equations` (the order doesn't matter as long as you're consistent), and I put the plots in their own subplots since they will probably have different scales.